# Right Align List Item Content in Ionic Framework

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am building an app with the Ionic Framework. It uses AngularJS and CSS. In my app, I need to display a list of items. Each item needs to look like the following:

```
+------------------------------------------+
| Item Title                         123   |
| one line of text                         |
| a seperate line of text                  |
+------------------------------------------+
```

I have everything working, except for the right-aligned number. The numbers are actually a `ul`. This is by design. They will be font icons that are colored differently. For now, I'm just trying to get the positioning to work. Currently, I'm trying the following:

```
<div class="list">
  <a class="item" style="left:0; right:0" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
    <p class="second-point">{{item.textA}}</p>
    <p class="third-point">{{item.textB}}</p>

    <ul class="row">
      <li class="col">1</li>
      <li class="col">2</li>
      <li class="col">3</li>
    </ul>
  </a>              
</div>
```

When this gets rendered, the numbers appear on a line underneath the first three text items. The ul is not right aligned. How do I get the component to be right-aligned?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with `float: right` on your `ul`, then apply `display:inline`on `li` (or float:left or display:inline-block) there many possibilities but inline seems to be easyiest to me for your situation. Last point your must change position of your `ul` because of float, you must put floating element at first inside parent block.

```
<div class="list">
    <a class="item" style="left:0; right:0" ng-repeat="item in items">
        <ul class="row">
            <li class="col">1</li>
            <li class="col">2</li>
            <li class="col">3</li>
        </ul>
        <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
        <p class="second-point">{{item.textA}}</p>
        <p class="third-point">{{item.textB}}</p>
    </a>              
</div>


    /*ul*/.row {
        float:right;
    } /* no need to precise your selector just a reminder */

    .row > li {
        display:inline;
    } /* selector for the "first child" li of ul, don't gonna apply on
    li inside your li, of course your can use .col like selector */
```